# Novice lookin for new router

Tags: 12.04, wireless, adapter

How do I know if my ubuntu 12.04 desktop pc uses adapter-g or adapter-n? I'm a novice and don't know where to find the info.  I have an Adapter-g wireless router.  When I connect through the modem, I get high speed.  When I connect through the router and modem, I get slower.  Both are Ethernet connections.  I have a Linksys wrt54g.  I know it needs replacing for my Comcast high speed but I don't want to buy an "n" if it's not compatible.

Answer (score 0):

Run `lspci` in terminal, and it will show what wifi card you have and it will even show you what modes does it support. (If it doesn't show the modes then just search for specifications on the internet.)

But I think you should buy an "n" router anyway. G routers are way too old, even "n" routers are being phased out.

Comment: Thanks, I was leaning that way.  Just didn't want to buy something that wasn't compatable.